# Wait till last function finish its work then in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating an small application in which i have 40 widgets which i am looping and fetching data and redrawing it.

```
    $scope.loopWiget = function(){
    for(var i=0; i < $scope.totalWidget.length; i++)
    {
     if($scope.totalWidget[i].widgetType == "chart"){
     $scope.fetchData($scope.totalWidget[i]);}
    if($scope.totalWidget[i].widgetType == "table"){
     $scope.fetchDataFortable($scope.totalWidget[i]);}
    }

     };

     $scope.fetchData = function(id){
    // fetching data and in response calling other function
    $http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'rest/dataset/metadata',
       type: 'json',
       headers:{'id':id}
     }).success(function(response){

    $scope.drawWid(response);
      }) 
     };
$scope.fetchDataFortable= function(id){
    // fetching data and in response calling other function
    $http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'rest/dataset/metaTabledata',
       type: 'json',
       headers:{'id':id}
     }).success(function(response){

    $scope.drawWidTable(response);
      }) 
     };
    $scope.drawWid = function(response){
      // All draw logic comes here
    };
$scope.drawWidTable= function(response){
      // All draw logic comes here
    };

$scope.totalWidget = [{'widgetId':'1','widgetType':'table'},{'widgetId':'2','widgetType':'chart'},{'widgetId':'3','widgetType':'maps'},{'widgetId':'4','widgetType':'chart'}];
    $scope.loopWiget();
```

Now my loop doesnt wait to complete drawWid function and calling fetchdata again due to this i am getting data of 2nd widget in 1st widget. so how to wait in loop till the draw function complete its code and then recall fetchData function for next widget.

Answer (score 0):

As this is an async request so this is common to render data randomly .There are few possible solutions for this :

First approach : store the data in a array from response and when all the data has been fetched then only call the draw function to render the widgets one by one or render the widget at the index of loop .

```
 widgets.forEach((widget, index) => {
            return this.myService.getData(widget.entityProp)
                .then(res => {
                    this.drawWid(res, index);
                });
 });


    drawWid(res, index) {
        compute logic accroding to the index of data .
    }
```

Second approach : you can use the $q.all() to fetch the data from all the request and then render it .

Comment: Thanks @sumit, for your answer can you suggest me with $q.all() with example as i cannot wait for all data to come.

Comment: Hi Mayur , What $q.all() is does to wait till all the request has been resolved while with the first approach you could pass the index or id as hash i.e 
 $scope.fetchData($scope.totalWidget[i].widgetId, i); here i will work as your id . now you can do the calculation according to the data you have got for the ID .

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following codes:

```
var index = 0;
$scope.loopWiget = function(){
    if(!$scope.totalWidget[index]){
        return;
    }
  var id = $scope.totalWidget[index]['widgetId'];

  if($scope.totalWidget[index].widgetType == "chart"){
        $scope.fetchData(id);
      }
      if($scope.totalWidget[index].widgetType == "table"){
         $scope.fetchDataFortable(id);
      }
 };

$scope.fetchData = function(id){
     $http({
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'rest/dataset/metadata',
           type: 'json',
           headers:{'id':id}
        }).success(function(response){
                $scope.drawWid(response);
                index++;

        });
}
$scope.drawWid = function(response){
  // All draw logic comes here
  $scope.loopWiget();
};

$scope.totalWidget = [{'widgetId':'1','widgetType':'table'},{'widgetId':'2','widgetType':'chart'},{'widgetId':'3','widgetType':'maps'},{'widgetId':'4','widgetType':'chart'}];
$scope.loopWiget();
```

Comment: Thanks @browen Li for your valuable time. I cannot change this way as i have to call an fetchData function because this function i used by many other places also so i cannot mve $http in loopwidget function. is there any other alternative?

Comment: Hi @Bowen Li, It is failing when i am calling for widgetType as table and maps.
Is there a way i can achieve from $q. any example

Comment: @Mayur how do you call for widgetType as table and maps?any demo codes?

Comment: i have edited my code. same logic is applied for maps too but i haven't mentioned the code.